# How to hold back JWT token in localstorage even after a page referesh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

Iam working in a login logout feature and iam using context api to run the function's like store token in localstorage and remove it wile logingout . "The problem is after login if i try to refresh the page the token stored in the localstorage is getting remove please tell me how do i encounter with this problem"

code of context :

```
 import React, {useState, createContext, useEffect} from 'react'
     import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

     const Authcontext = createContext(); 


     const Usercontext = ({children}) => {

     const navigate = useNavigate() 
     const [user, setuser] = useState(null)
     const [loggedin, setloggedin] = useState(false)
     const [token, settoken] = useState(null)

     useEffect(() => {
      const storedToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
      if (storedToken) {
        settoken(storedToken);
       }
     }, []);

    

    ////// Login activity
    const login = (value) =>{
      // const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(value))
        const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
        const base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
        const payload = JSON.parse(atob(base64));
        const currentuser = payload.user;
        setuser(currentuser)
        setloggedin(true)
     }


    ///// logout Activity
    const logout = () =>{
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
        setuser(null)
        setloggedin(false)
        navigate('/')
    }

    console.log(user);

    return (
    <Authcontext.Provider value={{user, loggedin, login, logout}} >
        {children}
    </Authcontext.Provider>
    )
    }

    export  {Usercontext, Authcontext};
```

here's my navabar code i've been trying to view the name of user in it . here is where the problem refelects after referesh the user name will be changed back to login and register :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { Authcontext } from '../context/Usercontext';
    import "../components/css/nav.css"

    export const Navbar = () => {

      const {loggedin, logout, user} = useContext(Authcontext)        

      console.log(user);

      return (
        <div className='navbar' >
          <div >Navbar</div>
           {loggedin ? (
            <div className='userin' >
             {user && user.username}
             <button className='btn' onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
            </div>
            ) : (
            <div className='userout' >
             <Link to="/register" className='register' >Register</Link>
             <Link to="/login" className='login' >Login</Link>
            </div>
           )}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

i've been trying to login activity with using localstorage . i need the token stored in the localstorage to hold back even after a page referesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Insted of**

```
const [token, settoken] = useState(null)
```

**Use**

```
const [token, settoken] = useState(localStorage.getItem('token'))
```

Because it will return null if the data for the specified key is not present in locaStorage.

Comment: Thank you for your response i mean's a lot to me. Finally it workt

Comment: Glad it helps you now. From my guess, you don't even need the storedToken variable as you got the local storage value in the loggedin variable itself.